# How to setup 301 redirects for a subdirectory using the htaccess file at Bluehost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having issues where my 301 redirects aren't functioning as expected when uploading the htaccess file to my hosting environment at Bluehost.
Most of the redirects work fine (those which are just static pages) but whenever testing the URL of a subdirectory page, the redirect is broken and I'm taken to a 404 page.

Here's an example of the htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /privacy https://wwwdotwebsite.com/
Redirect 301 /press https://wwwdotwebsite.com/about/
Redirect 301 /promotions/stars https://wwwdotwebsite.com/offers/
Redirect 301 /promotions/stripes https://wwwdotwebsite.com/offers/
```

So from the above, if I try to visit my site at "http://websitedotcom/promotions/stars" I get redirected to "https://wwwdotwebsite.com//offers/stars", so a 404.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: does stars page or directory?

Comment: Stars is a page within the promotions directory.

Comment: you need it to be redirected to offers directory not the same page there right?

Comment: Yeah that's right - just the offers page as the destination.

Comment: one minute , offers page as well? now i know stars  is page let me know if offers is page or directory ?

Answer (score 0):

As per Apache documentation whenever using `Redirect` it should be as follow:

***from page to page :***

```
Redirect "/foo.html" "/bar.html"
```

So , if `stars` is page and `offers` is also page put them with their extensions , for example :

```
Redirect 301 /promotions/stars.php https://wwwdotwebsite.com/offers.php
```

If not page to page and ***from directory to directory ***

```
Redirect 301 /promotions/stars/    https://wwwdotwebsite.com/offers/
```

**Note:** clear your browser cache then test .